# Better ways to display html content with apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

From what I understood, there are 2 ways to display html content with apps script :
Sidebar and a modal dialog box.

Problems:

- The modal box adds a couple extra clicks to display the content.
- The sidebar takes up too much space (too wide, too tall)

I'd like to have a simple floating square, always displayed, like a position:fixed div in the top-right corner of the sheet. Is it possible with apps scripts?

Comment: There is a toast as well. But no, that's not possible.

Comment: Perhaps if you share your code with us we can suggest improvements.  In my opinion either sidebar or dialog function the same.  I'm not sure what you mean by `extra clicks` for modal box and you can adjust the size, and the sidebar always has the same fixed size.